# Add Singleton to a Builder Class

Tags: java, singleton, builder

I have a Builder class as below, But i have no idea which is the correct way to make this class having **Singleton** behavior and remain my **Builder** pattern at the same time. Using some "single-element enum type"? or some [recommended](http://www.learn4master.com/design-pattern/java-singleton-pattern) way ?

```
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Getter
public class ClientMailAdapter {

public static ClientMailAdapter.WebLiteRequestBuilder builder() {
    return new ClientMailAdapter.WebLiteRequestBuilder();
}

@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public static class WebLiteRequestBuilder {
    private Map<String, String> parameters;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Source source;

    public ClientMailAdapter.WebLiteRequestBuilder parameters(final Map<String, String> parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
        return this;
    }

    public ClientMailAdapter.WebLiteRequestBuilder username(final String username) {
        this.username = username;
        return this;
    }

    public ClientMailAdapter.WebLiteRequestBuilder password(final String password) {
        this.password = password;
        return this;
    }

    public ClientMailAdapter.WebLiteRequestBuilder source(final Source source) {
        this.source = source;
        return this;
    }

    public ClientMailResult sendEmail() {
        return new ClientMailService().sendEmailXML(
                ClientRequest.builder()
                        .username(username)
                        .password(password)
                        .parameters(parameters)
                        .source(source)
                        .build());
    }
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum Source {
    XXXXX("Source Name To Be Defined X");

    private final String name;

}
```

}

Comment: There are several mistakes here. Also why do want this to be a singleton? Are you planning to re-use the single instance for other operations?

Comment: Unclear question. Are you trying to make a Singleton of the adapter or the builder? And why? Voting to close as unclear.  Furthermore, making a Singleton in general, and via an enum specifically, has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. **Search before posting.**

Comment: I need builder pattern because i will have large number of parameters to set. Meanwhile i need Singleton pattern for the client that use this class as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to do, but here goes: Maybe you need to separate the singleton from the builder. Create a singleton the standard way, by writing an enum with a single value. But in place of the builder class, create a configurator class that has permissions to set the options on the singleton. They should both sit in the same package, so you can keep the setters in the singleton accessible only by the configurator. There's no need for a builder if you're only building it once. Is that what you had in mind?